# How to find by data-* in object list

Tags: jquery

I have simple code which doesn't work:

```
jQuery('#list-of li').removeClass('active').find('[data-item-id="' + item_id + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Only works when I use it with `li` like

```
jQuery('#list-of li[data-item-id="' + item_id + '"]').addClass('active');
```

Comment: Can you show us the relevant HTML code please?

Comment: I've fixed the invalid JavaScript, since you claimed it was working I assumed in was a typo when pasting code here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use filter not find

find(): will look for decedent element, but you are already having the `li` elements from the previous set which is having the `data-item-id` attribute

filter(): will filter the current set of elements with the passed selector

```
jQuery('#list-of li').removeClass('active').filter('[data-item-id="' + item_id + '"]').addClass('active');
```